# How to inport text from MS Word via vba-commandbutton

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I am trying to make a configuration tool that is linked to several Excel-files.
They are all linked by an "option-number".
Are there any way to import a portion of a whole MS Word-document via the 
"option-number" link to Excel?

Comment: Yes this is possible. What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck? Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @RikSportel I am learning by doing and I have come so far as serching for alternativs. i found some questions about similar things on this site but i wanted to make a question as well. I noticed now that the texts that i wanted to improt was in table form so it should be easyer. Still, thank you for youre responce though it was  badly asked.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, since your question does not hold any code and doesn't really tell us much about the approach you're after, I'll just give some general pointers on how to access tables in a word document from an Excel macro.

First, you'll need to add a reference to the `Microsoft Word #.# Object Library`. To do this, open your VBE (alt+F11), click on `tools`, `References...` and check the checkbox for this library. The `#.#` above is the version number. For example word 2016 will be the `Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library`.

Now you'll have access to Word objects in your Excel VBE. 
You can do something like this:

```
Sub Test()
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim wTable As Word.Table
Dim r As Word.Row
Dim c As Word.Cell

Set wApp = New Word.Application 'Get a word application object, so you can open and manipulate documents from your Excel macro.
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\temp\temp.docx") 'Open your document.

Set wTable = wDoc.Tables(1) 'To access the first table in the document

For Each r In wTable.Rows 'Loop over Word table rows
    For Each c In r.Cells 'Loop over Word table cells
        'Do stuff with the table:
        MsgBox c.Range.Text
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = c.Range.Text
    Next c
Next r

'and clean up after yourself:
Set wTable = Nothing

wDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
wApp.Quit

Set wDoc = Nothing
Set wApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Good luck.

Comment: Can you explain this line a bit: 
Set wApp = New Word.Application 'Get a word application object, so you can open and manipulate documents from your Excel macro

Comment: `Set wApp = New Word.Application` opens/creates a Word instance. By default it is invisible. If you add `wApp.Visible = True` on the next line, you'll see what it did. The part after the ' is just a comment.
I assume the code will be part of an Excel macro, that's why you need the reference to a `Word.Application` object - Excel itself doesn't read word files.

Comment: Ok, so basically I make a macro that copies the table from Word into Excel and the macro is then linked to the VBA? Is it possible to determine which table it should copy via VBA or do I have to make one makro per table? In the workbook I am using there is an active table of "option-numbers" that varies from every project. The same "option-numbers" are in the Word-file i am copying from.

Comment: VBA is the programming language in which you write macros. 
You need a Macro in Excel that opens word documents and copies tables. 
My answer provides the starting point: open the word documents and finding the tables in there, so take it from there. 
This is the point where you start trying and write your own code. 
If you run into trouble, post a specific question with a code example so we can help you with that. We can't do your work for you - SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: So, now i tried to make my macro, that opens the word-file, copies and paste it in ecxel. I used some of the codes you gave me but since i don´t need to edit the table only copy it I deleted from "set wtable" to wDoc. When i tried to run it gives an error on the last row of the module. The error is 1004, pastespecial mothod in worksheet-class falied. the last row looks like this:     ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
        False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True

Comment: Good. So my answer was what you needed to get started. Mark it as such then. Next, you can ask a new and specific question for your new and specific problem, where you provide the code you have so far. People will be happy to help.

Comment: Will do, how do I get the code pasted in a more neat and readble way? Have been trying touse the formatting in the help link without success.

Comment: Just paste it, select it and click the {} button

Comment: Where do i find that button? Do I have to download google prettify?

Comment: Dude... When you write a question or an answer (and you're about to post a second question) there's some mark-up tools there above the field in which you write...